# Spring How to verify and validate a token in microservices

Tags: spring, jwt, microservices, token

I have a **gateway api** that communicates with a **ms1** (microservice 1) to get a token after that I should make http requests. I have a problem that I get the token from ms1 but I cant perform crud on ms1 using gateway, let's consider an example

```
gateway runs on port 8080

microservice1 runs on port 8090 with a class-path: /ms1
```

***1 >*** I send a request from gateway to ms1 to get the token like so (POST http://localhost:8080/ms1/oauth/token, this returns a access_token "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJKYWNrIiwia......"

***2 >*** When I add this token to the header and then send a request to do crud operations it doesnt work.

So my question should I make a verification in ms1 for that token that generated by the gateway api ?